# Disable a module from a specific view - Drupal 6

Tags: drupal-6

I am working on a site that is made entirely with Drupal 6 and have encountered a small issue. The site in question has two primary purposes;

1. To display a constant, premade ticker view to our clients and
2. to allow our staff members to chat with the DrupalChat module. However, the DrupalChat module keeps appearing on the ticker view and I can't find a way to fix that.

So my question is this: Is there any way to disable a specific module from appearing on a specific view, but still be fully available elsewhere on the site?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check with that chat module's configuration page. Check if it allows such a feature.